How to make the \widehat wider?
I want a wider \widehat as below?
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \text{se}(\hat{e}) = \sqrt{\widehat{\text{Var}(\hat{e})}} = \sqrt{\widehat{\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1x_0+\hat{\beta}_2x_0^2)}}
\]

I want the \verb|\widehat| wider to cober everything inside the \verb|\sqrt|, but it seems reach its wide limits?
\end{document}



ConTeXt supports stretching the hats, but at some point one shall also stop for a while and consider other notations.

@mickep could you make some parephrases about that? I didn't clear about it.

When the hat gets very wide (much wider than the available variants), it is not so easy to recognize it as a hat. In particular it might be difficult to distinguish it from a bar. See this example.

If you would like to use mtpro2, this is possible:
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
\[
  \text{se}(\hat{e}) = \sqrt{\widehat{\text{Var}(\hat{e})}} = \sqrt{\widehat{\text{Var}(\hat{\beta}_0+\hat{\beta}_1x_0+\hat{\beta}_2x_0^2)}}
\]

I want the \verb|\widehat| wider to cober everything inside the \verb|\sqrt|, but it seems reach its wide limits?
\end{document}



As for the mtpro2, I know that it is conflicted with amssymb, but if I want to typeset \mathbb{E}. is that best practice?

mtpro2 is incompatible with amssymb. To use the blackboard bold letters, you must load one of the package options: amsbb, mtphrb, mtpbb, mtphrd, mtpbbd.

I have found that in texdoc mtpro2 in  section 2.9, thanks!

The maximum size depends on the see font used. See the yhmath package which adds wider accents. (Also avoid testing with the minimal class, especially when testing fonts, and use \operatorname not \text)
Even with yhmath you reach the maximum width

\documentclass{article}
\NewCommandCopy\oldhat\hat
\usepackage{yhmath,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \operatorname{se}(\oldhat{e}) = \sqrt{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}(\oldhat{e})}} =
  \sqrt{\widehat{\operatorname{Var}(\oldhat{\beta}_0+\oldhat{\beta}_1x_0+\oldhat{\beta}_2x_0^2)}}
\]

I want the \verb|\widehat| wider to cover everything inside the
\verb|\sqrt|, but it seems reach its wide limits?
\end{document}

the package appears to have an issue with nesting \hat under \widehat so I used the original version for the nested accents.

The newer \widehat isn't satisfactory for me, I want the last one COVER from the latter V to the top of ) ,is that possible?

@Explorer as I say TeX can not stretch this at all, so it's a matter of choosing a font with a big enough accent, I see someone else suggested mtpro

Together with Stephen's solution, I further know your meaning and the yhmath package, thanks!

With the minimal option to yhmath the package doesn't override the standard math extension font.

@egreg oh you mean to avoid teh dance with the nested hats?
